# How to create a Chrome extension to detect online product listing, and periodically check for price changes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension that will detect product listing on major online shopping websites such as amazon, and place a "add to watchlist" button on the page.

When the user clicks the button, the product will be added to a list, which will be viewable, and the price of listed products will be periodically checked by the extension.

The extension will notify the user when any listed product's price changes.

Since I've just learnt how to create Chrome extensions, I would like to get an experienced developer's advice on how I should go developing such an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing you need to know is whether or not the product listing pages are publicly accessible or if you need to login in order to view those pages.

Getting data from restricted web sites via Chrome Extension can be quite difficult to implement.

If the product listing pages are publicly accessible, you can implement your Extension as follows:

1. Create the manifest.json (Version 2). Refer to a background-page script (e.g. bg.js). Add permission to all the product listing page URLs you have. Make it a browser action. Also add a popup (e.g. popup.html)
2. In bg.js implement a method to execute AJAX requests to those URL(s) and retrieve the results. Filter those results for the selected product prices. Store the latest results (for example in localStorage or in Google sync). If the product price has changed, change the badge of the browser action icon respectively
3. In popup.html refer to a popup.js, in which you implement a method to read all the latest results from localStorage/Google sync and show them inside the popup

One question from my side: You said

```
and place a "add to watchlist" button on the page
```

On which page? On the product listing page itself? Next to each product? What about products that are already on the "watchlist"?

Comment: Thanks for replying @devnull69. Yes I want the extension to detect product listing (which are public), whenever I visit the page, e.g. [link]http://www.amazon.com/Nexus-Google-7-Inch-Black-Tablet/dp/B00DVFLJDS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1396264663&sr=8-1&keywords=nexus+7[/link] the extension should modify the page, and place big visible button on that very page, which will add the listed product to extension's list, along with the product's price. The page, product name and price detection part is what eludes me.

Comment: Then you would have to add a content script to the manifest and your project. This content script will run on the product listing URLs and add the buttons to the page. On click of those buttons the content script will send the product and its price (via sendMessage) to the bg.js which will store it for future use.

Comment: While a persistent background page may ease development,  the final result should not need the persistence.

Comment: Edited. Of course you can also use an event page for bg.js